# Pass reference to a template class in Play2 framework template engine

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, twirl

I have a field.scala.html that should take a control as input and render it.

Right now I do like this:

```
@field("shop", "name", true) { (modelName, fieldName, required) =>
  @textInput(modelName, fieldName, required)
}
```

But I would like to do it like this:
@field("shop", "name", true)(textInput)

I see 2 ways it could be done but not sure if it's possible:

1. Somehow via reflection call the textInput.apply with appropriate
   parameters.
2. Make textInput implement some trait and field would
   require an instance of this particular trait (more type safe)

Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are just functions. If field.scala.html takes a:

```
(String, String, Boolean) => Html
```

And textInput.Scala.html has the following parameter declaration:

```
@(modelName: String, fieldName: String, required: Boolean)
```

Then what you want to do will just work. If not try passing textInput.apply.

Comment: Yes, @field("shop", "name", true)(textInput.apply) works. Is it possible to make template implement a trait?

Comment: I am only learning Play. Found out about template helpers. Will use them to write my own for generating angular js forms.